# improve search using a dict and pyahocorasick

Tags: python, python-3.x

I´m new at python and I don´t know how to program well. How do I edit this code so it can works using pyahocorasick? My code is very slow, because I need to search lots of strings at a very big file.
Any other way to improve the search?

```
import sys
with open('C:/dict_search.txt', 'r') as search_list:
    targets = [line.strip() for line in search_list]

with open('C:/source.txt', 'r') as source_file, open('C:/out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for line in source_file:
        if any(target in line for target in targets):
            fout.write(line)
```

Dict_search.txt

```
509344
827276
324194
782211
772854
727246
858908
280903
377881
247333
538710
182734
701212
379326
148310
542129
315285
840427
581092
485581
867746
434527
746814
749479
252045
189668
418513
624231
620284
(...)
```

source.txt

```
1,324194,20190103,0000048632,00000000000004870,0000045054!
1,701212,20190103,0000048632,00000000000147072,0000045055!
1,581092,20190103,0000048632,00000000000032900,0000045056!
(...)
```

I need to find the "word" from dict_search.txt is in the source.txt and if the word is on the line, i need to copy the line to other file.

The problem is that my source.txt is very big and I have more than 100k words at dict_search.txt

My code takes to execute. I tried using the set() method, but I got a blank file.

Comment: 'with' is a context manager, as soon as you get out of the 'with' it will automatically close the file and you are using targets variable assigned in one 'with' and using in another 'with'.It will not work.  But, you can open all the three files in single 'with'

Comment: It will be great if you can provide an example of how your dict_search.txt and source.txt look like.

Comment: @pk786 I added an example of the files. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It looks number from Dict_search.txt going to be match with second column in source.txt. Is it the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your files, it looks like **each line** in the *dict_search.txt* file match with the format of **second column** in *source.txt* file. If this is the case, the below code will work for you. It's a linear time solution so it's going to be fast on the cost of space because it creates dictionary in memory.

```
d={}
with open("source.txt", 'r') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        l = line.strip().split(",")

        d[l[1]]= line

with open("Dict_search.txt", 'r') as search, open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in search:
        row = line.strip()
        if row in d:
            output.write(d[row])
```